# Redefining Uart Alt Modes For Pinmuxing

Tags: yocto, u-boot, device-tree

I am working on to enable Wandboard Quad(IMX6Q) Uart 2 features for to get data from GPIO3_26 and GPIO3_27 I enabled Uart2 from dts and recompiled imx6q-wandboard.dtb file ,it seems its working but

when I send the "hello" to ttymxc1 I m seeing the senseless charachters , even if I adjust same baudrate ttymxc1 and my machıne ttyUSB0 (I m using usb to rs232 converter ). I think I need to close some features but I dont know what is it or I need to make some configuration pinmuxing and ALT modes . 
Is there any way to change the ALT modes of the features or when we choose the UART or another features it is enabling the dependent ALT Mode ?

Can you give me a suggestion or what Am I doing wrong ?

Must_ba

Comment: *"what Am I doing wrong ?"* -- (1) You haven't checked your Device Tree for pin conflicts.  (2) You cannot connect a *"usb to rs232 converter"* to the pins of an i.MX6Q (which are 3.3V logic).  (3) Why the `u-boot` and `yocto` tags?

Comment: Yes your are totally right , I noticed that yesterday :D I ordered  rs232 TTL converter  for check . I wonder if i burned the gpio pins that I connected to usb-rs232 converter . Could it be ?